# How to hold Email address collection more than 5

Tags: email, visual-workflow

I am using Visual flow to send Email address for particular object whenever the action is performed. I have used collection Variables to add the hold the address of the Email of the type text. When i am using sending email action in Visual flow, i am using the collection variables in Email address collection in visual flow.

I am getting the error:

```
We can't save this record because the “Flow process for sending emails” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. too many additional emails - max 5:
```

How can i send more than 5 receipents in email in visual flow. Is any other way?

Comment: To keep it declarative, you would need to either create a number of Email instances where each instance has a maximum of 5 additional emails OR you can create a distribution list on the email server if the recipients are within the same company (a task by company admins). If neither of the above fit, moving this requirement to Apex will give you greater control but still has limits, just higher.

Comment: @TSmith,could you please ellaborate in detailed manner for how to use in Visual flow for adding more receipents in mail

Comment: @TSmith,How to use in flow.

Answer (score 1):

So, ran into this myself just now, and to borrow from TSmith's comment, you have a few options.

First, you can split the email in question into multiple actions via copy-paste, each with a different five recipients (but the same subject and body).
This is easiest to do if you're using a static list of recipients; if you're not, the next level up is either a loop over the collection of users (or whoever) you're trying to email, sending the email to the "current item from [variable]" loop target's email each time.

Your recipient field should look something like:
"{!Loop_name.email_field_name__c}",
or "{!Loop_name.Email}".

This is probably the choice I'd pick for the specific situation you described.

Alternatively, you can use the "send email *alert*" action instead of the "send email" action; *that* requires setting up the email alert outside the flow: all you do from inside the flow is pass it the relevant record ID. This is probably not ideal for your circumstances, since email alerts don't have particularly good options for dynamic recipients, but it does get around the 5-recipient limit *if* they're internal users.

Apex code will work too, but that appears to be out of scope of the question as asked (and commented), and will be more difficult to maintain besides, because admins and apex coders only overlap so much, and maintenance will require both.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the UnofficialSf.com [Send Better Email](https://unofficialsf.com/send-better-email-flow-action/) component which supports 150 email addresses

> **Standard Email** – The preferred choice. When in doubt, select this option. It provides far more powerful customization options for recipient selection (including the use of standalone text email addresses), message formatting, and more. However, this mode limits the number of recipients (150) per message and the number of different messages per invocation (10) you can use.

The email addresses can come from a variety of sources:

> **Set Addressees**
>
> You can use the following data sources:
>
> A single text email address
>
> A string collection of email addresses
>
> A collection of Contacts
> A collection of Users
>
> A collection of Leads

Answer (score -1):

I Implemented the below **solution** and you can also try.

***********************************************************************

**Loop through the collection and send an email to the current item in the loop.**

***********************************************************************

Comment: A loop is already discussed in existing answers. If you had presented your solution in detail, it could have been of use to someone. As such it just fills space on StackExchange, or have I overlooked something?